# Can Heroku users take advantage of Postgres schemas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Can Heroku users take advantage of Postgres schemas and search paths?

That is, using the standard Heorku database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer, yes.

The doubters can find a [sample app](http://multi-tenant.heroku.com/), and [source code](https://github.com/dapplebeforedawn/multi-tenant-app)

Comment: But they do not recommend using schemas in the case of SAAS applications, or where you would have a large number (50+) of schemas: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql